# Not getting regular service bus messages when configuring to receive messages from deadletterqueue

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-functions-runtime

this is how my azure function code looks like..

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue/$DeadLetterQueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]Message myQueueItem, ILogger log, int deliveryCount,
            string messageId,
            string deadLetterSource,
            System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> UserProperties
            )
        {}
```

I am able to get deadletter messages, but somehow not receiving regular messages from the service bus queue,

Is this expected behaviour?

if so how can i receive regular/deadletter messages in the same function.

I am using function 2.0 runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Azure Function does not support receiving from more than a single source.
A queue and its dead-letter queue are considered two different queues.
You will need to have two Functions with some shared logic.